# How to quickly access shared files in Ubuntu 14.04 from Windows XP in VirtualBox?

Tags: virtualbox

In my PC, running on Ubuntu 14.04, I have installed VirtualBox, and then Windows XP SP3 in it as the guest. I have also installed Guest Addition, mainly for accessing files in any of the several partitions in my HDD from the Windows, and I have been successfully doing so. The snag, however, is that my *method* for doing this seems way too roundabout (Windows Explorer>My Network Places>Entire Network>\VBOXSVR...etc). So my questions are two:
    1. Can anyone suggest a *quicker way*?   2. And,paradoxically, the shared folder cannot be accessed by going directly to My Network Places but only via Windows Explorer. Why?

Comment: This is entirely a Windows issue, nothing Ubuntu can do about.

Answer (score 0):

Windows sometimes doesn't see other machines, something to do with NetBIOS broadcasts?!. it should always be available through direct \\IP_ADDRESS in explorer (note the 2 backslashes). You can also access it using the PC name \\VBOXSVR.

[This info here is windows 7](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/create-shortcut-map-network-drive#1TC=windows-7) but its the same process, Just add the required shared network path as a Network drive so you can just access it with a drive letter in future.

I think it also helps if both machines are set to the same Workgroup name.